# What is our stance on questions asking for health data sets off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

What is our stance on questions asking for health data sets off-topic? I know they are on-topic on OpenData.SE, but I am curious to know whether they are allowed in this Stack Exchange.

Example:

[Is there a data source indicating how long most major surgeries take, and what are the associated risks/outcomes?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/1690/43)

> I'm looking to play around with statistics around major surgery types; is there a publicly available data source I can work with which lists information such as:
>
> - types of major surgeries, together with amount of time per procedure (average, standard deviation, broken down by complication, etc...)
> - risk information to any level of detail
> - any sort of other aggregate information
>
> Any data set would be interesting (i.e., for any geographical region or legal jurisdiction - I know some of this info might be harder to collect in say the US than elsewhere)

Comment: Another (more recent) example: https://health.stackexchange.com/q/15907/8212

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma Thanks, related: [What is our stance on questions about asking for a specific number?](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/q/610/43)

Comment: If you're doing research and that's why you need the data, then you should be capable of doing the research yourself.  Or ask in chat.  If you're not doing research and just interested in the data, then make the effort to look this up yourself.  This is more about academic research which I don't think should be our domain.

Comment: @GrahamChiu "then you should be capable of doing the research yourself. " -> yes but it takes time, hence the usefulness of publicly sharing such QAs.

Comment: Then if there is a resulting publication, please add us as authors :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think these questions should be closed as off-topic or migrated to OpenData.SE

The reason for this is that data sets can be used in many different ways and it is all about how they are interpreted. In order for anyone to be able to make use of data sets, they need to be able to interpret the data sets into meaningful information based on the study they wish to conduct.

This SE site is not a statistics (CrossValidated.SE) or a data analysis site, so we should migrate or close them as off-topic.