# What is our stance on questions about asking for a specific number?

Tags: discussion, scope, allowed-questions

What is our stance on questions about asking for a specific number?  Are they on-topic or off-topic?

[Example](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/7254/43):

> Question: Number of MRI scanners in the world today?
>
> How many MRI scanners are there today in the whole world? My own
>   search only revealed numbers in certain countries but no overall
>   count.

Comment: IMO that particular question about MRIs is unanswerable. Who would know the exact number...

Comment: @Lucky approximation would be fine too I guess

Comment: I would expect that someone working in the marketing department of an MRI scanner manufacturer probably knows a very close estimate, possibly even an exact number.

Comment: @CareyGregory That [sounds a lot](http://www.physics.umd.edu/perg/fermi/fermi.htm) like a [Fermi Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem). Guess the number of hospital beds in a hospital, expand to beds per 100,000 people, get MRI scanners per 100,000 people and approximate for the world. [xkcd has done an even more mundane task.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/63/). I guess that in the end, we just need someone with the time to do it.